# The bot for Discord does not respond to commands

Tags: python, discord

## I tried to change the syntax, maybe there are problems with it, but no. I would be glad to help and if possible detailed. And because I'm a beginner, I don't understand a bit what my problem is

The bot simply does not respond and does not react at all

```py
import discord
import googlesearch
import wikipedia
import youtube_search
import youtube_dl
import requests
import random
from discord import Embed
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='JE.', intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user}')

@bot.command()
async def google(ctx, *, query):
    search_results = googlesearch.search(query, num_results=5)
    response = ''
    for result in search_results:
        response += f'{result}\n'
    await ctx.send(response)

@bot.command()
async def wiki(ctx, *, query):
    try:
        search_results = wikipedia.search(query)
        page = wikipedia.page(search_results[0])
        embed = Embed(title=page.title, url=page.url, description=page.summary)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    except:
        await ctx.send('Couldn\'t find the article.')

@bot.command()
async def youtube(ctx, *, query):
    search_results = youtube_search.search(query, max_results=1)
    if search_results:
        video_url = f'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={search_results[0]["id"]}'
        embed = Embed(title=search_results[0]['title'], url=video_url, description=search_results[0]['description'])
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    else:
        await ctx.send('Couldn't find the video.')

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

Comment: Is that your real secret token in `bot.run`? Revoke it if so, because you’ve just made it public.

Comment: Thank you for noticing and prompting

Comment: About which command are we talking here?